# Fontis Australia Magento Extension is enabled from admin side but not displayed in shipping method

Tags: php, magento

I successfully installed "Fontis  Australia Magento Extension" and then enabled that extension and fill required fields from admin side  but at front side its not displayed in shipping method section.

Comment: not a magento user but have you tried erasing the cache? =/ trying to help...

Comment: have you enabled that shipping method in backend

Comment: can you see it in backend shipping method?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are a variety of reasons that it might not be showing up. We've listed a few of the common ones in the instructions on our website:

http://www.fontis.com.au/magento/extensions/australia

You might also want to try clearing the cache, as suggested above, and checking that none of your custom templates or layouts are causing conflicts. Another thing we sometimes run into with Magento is incorrect permissions on the var/ directory, which can cause all sorts of weird behaviour.

Comment: i follow all these instruction and also clear cache memory many times but still didn't displayed.

Comment: Are there any other caches that might be getting in the way, such as APC?

Comment: I had same issue. Fixed it by changing the weight unit setting "Products Use Units" to Grams. Australia Post ships only 20Kg max

Comment: Its an old post, still I am getting this issue. Store I am using also has units in GRAMS. Is there anything in FONTIS extension, we can make FONTIS to calculate in GRAMS and not in KGs. I did not find the weight unit setting with the FONTIS extension I installed. Is there anything I am missing.